# using a graph in R in Powerpoint

Tags: r, graph, plot, powerpoint

I have certain x and y coordinates for the position of an animal for a certain time t-max. I am using the code in R:

```
for (t in 1:tmax) {
plot(x[1:t],y[1:t]);
Sys.sleep(0.1);
}
```

to see how the animal is moving with time. So this shows me the path from each value of x to the subsequent value, till tmax. So now i have to present my findings in a Powerpoint presentation. so i was wondering if there is a method to insert this graph in a slide so that when i click a button, the graph is plotted and everybody can understand how the animal is moving.

Comment: Here's another approach that should be OS agnostic me thinks: http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/animate-gif-images-in-r-imagemagick/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on the Animation-Package on Cran:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html

Comment: Or specifically, see `?saveGIF` or `?saveSWF` or `?saveVideo` in the `animation` package, all of which can be inserted into Powerpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of animation, and in this case it doesn't seem useful.  Why not just plot the graph, or if the path is seriously tangled, plot with a rainbow colormap applied to the line so you can easily follow from start to finish?  See `plotrix::color.scale.lines`

Answer (score 1):

The animations package is cool, but i found it hard to learn. Instead of sleeping after each point is plotted, you could save the graph, and then use a video editor to merge the graphs into a movie clip. Windows movie maker will do this for you.

Comment: Not much use for non-Win users :-( .  To be fair, there are plenty of equivalent video tools on other platforms.  I've used GraphicConverter on OSX to do this.

Comment: True. I stupidly assumed the OP was on windows cause he mentioned Powerpoint. Not a reasonable assumption at all.

Comment: K  Don't be so hard on yourself.  Even good people sometimes use Windows :-)

Comment: the OP is windows :D and this is a she :)

Comment: Probably I need more efforts on documentation... Step 1: install ImageMagick; Step 2: put your code in `saveGIF({...})` and you are done with a GIF animation.